# How do I connect to localhost with NppFTP?

Tags: notepad++

I am unable to get Notepad++'s NppFTP to connect as localhost to my Windows XP.
I want to "upload" the current file from a "src" directory to the local /xampp/htdocs directory during development.

Ironically, I *am* able to connect remotely to my eventual deployment server.

Settings are:

```
Hostname: localhost
Connection type: FTP
Port: 21
Initial remote directory: \xampp\htdocs\junk
```

Comment: Have you tried using 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost?

Answer (score 3):

If you're running on Windows, make sure you're running your XAMPP control (XAMPP UI) as admin. Then, you have yo check the SVC checkbox before FileZilla, then click *Start*. 
A pop-up will prompt – click *Yes* to install it as a service.

After that, click *Admin* then click *Yes*. Set your password then you're good to go.

In you're using Notepad++, the settings are the same with the one you posted above.

Comment: In Mac OS you need to run it as admin? Because my xampp doesn't connect via FTP (FileZilla and Atom or Dreamweaver) with the same configurations